# Apache CXF wdsl2java code generation without service element

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, onvif

I'm trying to develop a client for onvif which has wsdl as in:

http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl

The wsdl2java runs fine and code is generated. However, because there is no  element in the wsdl, it doesn't generate a service class for me to use. It only generate an interface for the  element.

The webservice's endpoint URI will be different for each device where the service is provided. My question is, given that URI, how am I supposed to get an instance of the portType interface, so that I could use the interface to interact with the webservice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need it to create a service class to utilize the generated stub. It is possible to use something similar to the following:

```
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean;

...

protected <T> T getService(final Class<T> serviceClass, final boolean useSoap12) {
    final JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setServiceClass(serviceClass);
    factory.setAddress(endpoint);
    if (useSoap12) {
        factory.setBindingId("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/");
    }
    return serviceClass.cast(factory.create());
}
```

Where `serviceClass` is the annotated interface CXF created.